# No overload for method take 0 arguments

Tags: c#, web-services, methods, parameters, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem. I have add a service reference with a WSDL file and I need to pass some parameters in a method but I don't know what to enter

```
 Invited.SubjectViewContent[] nc = proxy.GetSubjectViewContents();
```

In the part where it says proxy.GetSubjectViewContents() inside the parenthesis its shows me the follow:

```
Invited.SubjectViewContent[] Dashboard.GetSubjectViewContent(string projectID, string[] subjectIDs, string CurrentUserID, string Language)

Error:
  No overload for method 'GetSubjectViewContents' takes 0 arguments
```

I been trying to pass some parameters but I don't really know how to begin.

Thanks for your time

Comment: So it needs a `projectId`, `subjectIds`, `currentUserId` and `language`.  You need to pass those in.  You need to know what those are in order to use the method.  If you dont, then you have no business calling it.  No one here can answer that question.

Comment: Hi, I do know what are those and all are string, the question is I have to pass them as string projectId = "123" or initialize it outside the method. I was not expecting that someone figure out from me the content just how to begin and call it with the write syntax.

Comment: @user3790916: In that example the variable `projectId` would be what you pass to the method as its first parameter.  Are you just asking about basic C# language syntax?  An introductory tutorial on C# would probably be a good first step here.

Comment: hi, yes I will try to look about how to pass the parameters if I know the projectId already. thanks anyways

Comment: `proxy.GetSubjectViewContents("123", "234", "345", "English");`

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I made the change that you suggest me but I get the follow error (The best overloaded method match for 'GetSubjectViewContents.Invited.Dashboard.GetSubjectViewContents(string, string[], string, string)' has some invalid argumentsGetSubjectViewContents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I have to create an array since the parameters inside the method one was an array. So I did the follow

```
 string subjName = "Dat";
            string[] stringArray = new string[]{subjName};

Invited.SubjectViewContent[] nc = proxy.GetSubjectViewContents("54f08a8-dcc6-4f3d-8ba6", stringArray, "", "");
```

Thanks for all the help